# Refer to the user in API URL (me, my or self)

Tags: api-design

Is there a known best practice when referring to the authenticated user in an API URL?
For example, the Facebook API uses `/me` as a prefix to all the resources of the authenticated user.
But I can think of other solutions such as `/my`, `/self` or the long one `/users/{id}`.
Is it just a matter of preference/taste? or are there good reasons to choose one over another?

Comment: Current or active seems more appropriate from a code perspective.

Comment: What about a simple GET : /user (in singular, not plural)

Comment: @MartinMaat You mean something like `/users/[current|active]`?

Comment: @Laiv Because as a common practice I reserve the use of a singular resource to singleton resources. And I'm planning to have /users and co resources so that you can access public resources of other users. Of course it does not prevent to have a /user resource but then I would find it confusing from the API consumers perspective.

Comment: Then, /me looks to me the one I would go for. It's matter of tastes. /active make me think in /inactive (status) and /current make me think in iterations.